# Understanding the subsets of $L^2(G)$ whose heighest weight of irrep constitutents is bounded.

Tags: representation-theory, hilbert-spaces, lie-groups, lp-spaces

I'm trying to read a paper on Random walks on compact lie groups [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1209.1745.pdf). On Pg. 28, one of the key Lemmas that I'm interested in makes use of a specific subset $\mathcal{H}_r \subset L^2(G)$ and then proceeds to construct an identity on it. For the purposes of my research, it is important that I understand what this space is, its properties, more examples and preferably a thorough study of it (if any). I was able to find any reference about these functions. Could any one please provide me any good references on $\mathcal{H}_r$ spaces?

The definition of $\mathcal{H}_r$ from the paper is the following:

> If $G$ is a compact connected semi-simple Lie group, the space
>   $L^2(G)$ can be decomposed as an orthogonal sum of finite dimensional
>   irreducible representations. We write $\mathcal{H}_r\subset L^2(G)$
>   for the sum of those constituents which have highest weight $v$ with
>   $|v|\le r$.

Thanks in advance!